# Update Command Works Too Slow in MySql Database (Java)

Tags: mysql, database

I Have a Server Dealing With Database, I Have Used Alot of Commands All Going Well, But This one Is Terribly Slow in matter of Time, When tries to Execute The Update Command :

```
UPDATE reza585276 SET like='updated' WHERE _id=2
```

Please Any Idea What is The Reason of Being Slow? I Have Tested it on MYsql WorkBench and works falwless and my Database is Not That Big.

Comment: "I Have a Server Dealing With Database, I Have Used Alot of Commands All Going Well," - do you have some sort of fixation on the SHIFT key? :-)

Comment: Your right , hehe :D

Comment: This code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: This approach leads the concept of prepared statements astray. Prepared statements are precompiledparameterized reusable sql queries.

Comment: Did you try [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) ?

Comment: you mean i shouldnt use prepared Statements for Existance check?

Comment: And you don't have to check for table existance before accessing it. You will catch an exception if it doesn't but that's what exceptions are made for. Count operates on the complete table and may result in a full table scan depending on the dbms you are using. So if your table consists of a million entries the execution may obviously take quite a while.

Comment: `Tested it on MYsql WorkBench and works falwless`.. does this mean its fast on MYsql WorkBench?

Comment: yep its fast enought of it

Comment: well dude, i am trying to make my server Fail-safe, since there gonna be too many requests of it. wouldnt the server stop it sql command be wrong or table or row doesnt exist?

Comment: Because you are actually only updating table entries which match a certain criteria you can reduce the statements to one update.. where

Comment: No it absolutely will not affect your server in terms of stopping or crashing and neither your knowledge of Java prepared statements nor your knowledge of your dbms gives you a authorization of calling me a dude. Thinking an invalid sql statement will crash your server is rather naiv.

Comment: i will also try to remove checkers, thanks alot for caring dude..em Sir

Comment: I am an Android Programmer not java, what you said hurts but your kinda right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A statement like `UPDATE reza585276 SET like='updated' WHERE _id=2` is slow when the DB server has to read the whole table to find the row with `_id=2` and there are many, many rows.

Try to add an index on this column.

If the index isn't the problem, then some other process/thread might be updating the same table or row. Make sure you don't keep connections around forever, that you commit transactions properly and timely.

Also check the error logs of the DB server (maybe a hard disk is failing) and make sure you properly handle errors in your application (instead of, say, swallowing them).

Comment: nah i have a maximum of 100 rows, not that big, so the problem is not with my code is it?

Comment: OP says `Tested it on MYsql WorkBench and works flawless`. So maybe index is not a problem here

Comment: The next person reading this would be glad to hear which one helped :-)

Comment: + using stmt.executeUpdate(UpdateSQL);

Comment: sure , i restarted Database, And Stopped Other Threads to Working with the same Table at once, and used   stmt.executeUpdate(UpdateSQL) instead of stmt.execute(UpdateSQL). Thanks Goes to All

Comment: @reza: The last one shouldn't make a big difference.